# Ubuntu 14.04 taking far too long to start

Tags: 14.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but I find that it takes far too long to start up.

Each time that I switch on my computer, first the American Megatrends logo appears and then, after a while, the screen goes blank and remains blank for almost 3 minutes before the Ubuntu logo kicks in.  Only then does the Ubuntu desktop appears.

Is this normal or could the problem be due to defective hardware?  All responses would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Ctrl Alt F1. then type these commands:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```